# Investing into a fixed bike

Tags: repair, fixed-gear, single-speed, paint

Well, two weeks ago I bought this fixed-gear bike and although it was my first time buying one of its kind, I considered it was cheap.

Problem here is that when I tried to search for any clue of the brand... oh surprise, there's no brand!

I was told that it was a pure cycle fixed bike, but I realized that it was painted over and the only thing that I have is a serial number that throws no information when I search it on the web.

Should I invest my money in add the front brake? And also all of the details that it has? (Bad paint job, change relatively new wheels, fight the rust that is forming in the gear?)

I paid $80 USD. And I bought it mostly because I wanted to have a fixed bike and to start learning to repair bikes. Could I sell it for more than the final price that will cost to me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE Bicycles.  We consider valuation questions off topic because they are of very limited use.  Your bike is valued by you at $80 US because you paid that much for it.   Re the brakes, if the laws in your location requires two independent braking systems then you should fit one that works.  If you're having buyer's remorse, then go ride it more.  If you don't like it after a month, relist it on CL or ebay or whatever and take what you get for it.

Comment: As you are a novice fixie rider, I suggest you add the brake. It may not be give the hip, clean line, babe pulling, macho look you are after, but the end result of losing footing from pedals at high speed won't either.

Comment: But bruised and bleeding ankles and shins from pedals flying around at high speed are so hip!  :-)

Comment: Public service announcement: Cheap and shoddy paint over everything recognizable equals obviously stolen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, add the brake - as others have said, it might not be 'cool' but you'll end up being much more confident on it knowing you can stop it quickly. I also can't work out if you have foot retention or not from the picture, but even with a brake I'd highly recommend some kind of foot retention, and if you ride brakeless you are pretty much unable to stop at all without it.
2. If you like it and it fits, keep it. If you don't really like it, or it doesn't fit then it doesn't sound like you'll lose too much by selling it.

I'd get a brake on it and make sure it's serviceable then ride it for a while and see how you like it. Riding fixed takes some getting used to, so get some miles in before making your mind up!

Comment: The cool factor is irrelevant if the bike requires two brakes by local law. :)